# How to open communication PYTHON socket with a SERVER SOCKET on AWS EC2 to a CLIENT SOCKET on my local pc?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python, hosting, socket

Sorry my english is not good

I want to established connexion from my client socket on my local pc to a host server socket on AWS EC2 instance.

I'm trying to follow suggestions from here and code from here.

The issue I'm facing is that I do not know how to open a socket and listen to incoming traffic on EC2. My EC2 is a UBUNTU free tier instance. No matter what I try I can't get it to work.

Someone said here that you have to put the private address of the EC2 on the client side and the public address on the server side. But I don't know specifically what address it is especially since I'm using an ubuntu engine

And how to run socket server program 24/7 ?

I would appreciate if somebody showed me how to do this properly.

Please please

That is how i'm try

[Here is a part of code from my server socket on AWS EC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el2P9.png)

[Here is a part of code from my client socket on my local pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQEia.png)